# In "Stranger things" S01, How was wormhole in the base of a tree in the woods created?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

In series "**Stranger things**" season 1, How were **two** worm holes (Ones that would open doors to parallel universe or Up-side-down) created? To be specific, How was wormhole in the base of a tree in the woods created?

Comment: If you watched the series you'd remember it was not shown _how_ they were created. The monster just creates them and go through.

Comment: if one of the answers fulfils the question, don't forget to mark it as correct. Otherwise at least add a comment on why you think it's not correct. We don't want questions open forever.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Remember the tightrope and the flea explanation... the monster was the flea.

The monster was able to cross between the realities, he would tear through to get something, but those holes would then close up again. They wouldn't be used a second time.

Answer (score 4):

The only holes that were shown were the one in the lab (right after the failed experiment with Eleven in the isolation tank) and the one in Will's house (the monster rips the wall open).

In [Chapter 5 - The Flea and the Acrobat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stranger_Things_(TV_series)):

> While searching, Nancy and Jonathan find a wounded deer. As they are about to perform a mercy kill on it, the creature drags it away.

Obviously the creature created that portal in the tree, but it is not shown  *how* it was created.

The Demogorgon also snatches Barb from the swimming pool, but it's not shown where did he come from.

Comment: I wonder why the downvotes. Somebody care to explain what's wrong with the answer?

Comment: In your comment you say the monster creates them, which is correct, but you say the one in the tree was just there in this answer. Remember the monster took the body of the deer that had been hit by a car. It created the hole in the tree to get to the deer.

Comment: @ToddWilcox just rewatch the episode: _obviously_ the creature made the portal in the tree, but it is not shown on the screen. Nor is the creature: we just see the deer and the blood trail leading to the hole.