# Did the "Department of Energy" open any of the gates to the Upside-down?

Tags: plot-explanation, stranger-things

It seems like a strange coincidence that the "stable" gate to the upside-down in *Stranger Things* is within a Department of Energy facility.

But it seems like they're taken by surprise by it. And from what I've read and seen, it's the Demogorgon that is opening the other gates.

Did the DoE open the stable gate? Was it on purpose?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They opened the gate inside Department of Energy but by mistake. DoE were trying to telepathically intercept information from a Russian spy by use of Eleven's powers but it goes wrong and she came across the monster who we call Demogorgon and create the stable gate while coming back. It was cleared in Chapter Five: The Flea and the Acrobat.

Demogorgon did seem to be able making temporary gates as cleared in [another question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/57568/in-stranger-things-s01-how-was-wormhole-in-the-base-of-a-tree-in-the-woods-cr).